# Как вытащить из Oracle скрипты создания tablespace?

Tags: oracle

Существует ли возможность вытащить скрипты создания tablespace из рабочей БД Oracle используя какой нибудь пакет ?

Смотрел в сторону DBMS_METADATA, но не нашел способа получить скрипты через него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885) возвращает выражение `CREATE TABLESPACE`:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLESPACE', 'TS_NAME')
from dual
```

вместо `TS_NAME` подставьте имя нужного пространства.